# java string to json element conversion

Tags: java, json, string, element

I am trying to convert java string object into Jsonelement by given code , but getting error for line -- JsonElement jelement = ((Object) new JsonParser()).parser(result);

```
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/Priyanka/Documents/json/temp.json"));

    StringBuilder content=new StringBuilder();
    String result=null;
    String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          content.append(line);
        }

     reader.close();
     result= content.toString();
     JsonElement jelement = ((Object) new JsonParser()).parser(result); // Error line

     printJsonRecursive(result);
```

Comment: What is this error? And what does your json look like?

Comment: Why are you casting JsonParser to Object?

Answer (score 2):

As Fedy2 stated on comments you are casting JsonParser to Object. Object doesn't have method parser() so it gives compilation error. Just remove that cast and compilation error should be gone.

Your JSON is missing one brace } at the end.

Comment: BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("temp.json"));
        StringBuilder content=new StringBuilder();
        String result=null;
        String line = null;
          
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            result= content.toString();
            JSONParser parser= new JSONParser(); 
            Object obj= parser.parse(result);
            JsonElement jelement= (JsonElement) obj;
            printJsonRecursive(jelement);

Comment: I made above changes , though code is getting compiled but its giving run time error at parser.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 422.
 at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at json.main(json.java:39)

Comment: Could you print out what your result object contains? (System.out.println(result);)

There seems to be something wrong with your JSON

Comment: its content of Json file.

Comment: So what does your JSON file contain? The problem is not anymore in your code but in your JSON.

Comment: {    "descriptor" : {        "app1" : {            "name" : "mehdi",            "age" : 21,            "messages": ["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]        },        "app2" : {            "name" : "mkyong",            "age" : 29,            "messages": ["msg 11","msg 22","msg 33"]        },        "app3" : {            "name" : "amine",            "age" : 23,            "messages": ["msg 111","msg 222","msg 333"]        }    }

Comment: This is the o/p of result

Comment: You are missing one brace at the end. Add } to end of file and you should be fine. (also modified my answer to contain solution for this JSON problem)